# Problems putting coordinates on a textbox for DragEnd event with Subgurim Maps

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, textbox, subgurim-maps

I'm trying to create a draggable marker with Subgurim and reading the final variables to textboxes.

I've got all working, except the part where I put the coords on a textbox.

The codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (SessionManager.User == null) {
        string strscript  = "<script language=javascript>window.top.close();</script>";
        if(!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientScript")) {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "clientScript", strscript);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {                
            gmap.Height = 400;
            gmap.Width = 590;
            gmap.enableDragging = true;
            gmap.Language = "pt";
            gmap.BackColor = Color.White;
            gmap.enableDragging = true;
            gmap.enableGoogleBar = true;

            gmap.Language = "pt";
            gmap.BackColor = Color.White;

            GControl nav = new GControl(GControl.preBuilt.LargeMapControl3D);
            GControl maptypes = new GControl(GControl.preBuilt.MenuMapTypeControl, new GControlPosition(GControlPosition.position.Top_Right));
            GControl scale = new GControl(GControl.preBuilt.ScaleControl, new GControlPosition(GControlPosition.position.Bottom_Left));
            GControl overview = new GControl(GControl.preBuilt.GOverviewMapControl, new GControlPosition(GControlPosition.position.Bottom_Right));

            gmap.addControl(nav);
            gmap.addControl(maptypes);
            gmap.addControl(scale);
            gmap.addControl(overview);

            GLatLng pt=null;
            int zoom = 16;

            string lat = Request.QueryString["lat"];
            string lon = Request.QueryString["lon"];

            if (lon == null || lat == null) {
                pt = new GLatLng(Helper.BASE_LAT, Helper.BASE_LON);
                zoom = Helper.BASE_ZOOM;
            }
            else {
                pt = new GLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(lat), Convert.ToDouble(lon));
            }
            gmap.setCenter(pt,zoom);

            GMarkerOptions mOpts = new GMarkerOptions();
            mOpts.draggable = true;

            GMarker marker = new GMarker(pt,mOpts);
            gmap.addGMarker(marker);

            gmap.addListener(new GListener(marker.ID, GListener.Event.dragend,
                string.Format(@"
                   function(overlay, point)
                   {{
                      var ev = new serverEvent('myDragEnd', {0});
                      ev.addArg({0}.getZoom());
                      ev.addArg(this.getPoint());
                      ev.send();
                   }}
                   ", gmap.GMap_Id)
                )
            );
        }
    }
}

protected string gmap_ServerEvent(object s, GAjaxServerEventOtherArgs e) {    
    switch (e.eventName) {
        case "myDragEnd":
            string zoomLevel = e.eventArgs[0];
            GLatLng point = GAjaxServerEventArgs.latlngFromString(e.eventArgs[1]);
            txtLat.Text = "Hello";//point.lat.ToString();
            txtLon.Text = "There";//point.lng.ToString();
        break;
    }
    return string.Empty;    
}
```

Basically I am creating a draggable marker and attaching an event to it, which is handled by the last method where the assignment is done... which doesn't happen. The textboxes still show empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you add the marker

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', markerDrag);
```

then in header

```
function markerDrag(evt)
                 {
                    document.getElementById('mlat_').value = this.getPosition().lat();
                    document.getElementById('mlng_').value = this.getPosition().lng();

                 }
```

where mlat_ and mlng are input type text